# Cannot get response for requests that are over abt 5 minutes on AWS load-balanced environment

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We are sending a POST request that could take a couple of minutes from our application registered as a windows service on one AWS server to our API which is located in an AWS load-balanced environment. Both are C# .Net 4.7.2 projects.

The request could take 1 - 60 minutes depending on the data amount. And we notice that for requests that take more than around 5 minutes, there is a big chance that the request would be lost. We have adde detailed logs at both ends to ensure that the response is generated and sent out from our API, but no response or error message is received on the other end. Since we set an one-hour cancelationToken for the request, so at last the request would failed due to timeout after one hour, however according to the logs we added, the response should have been sent out a long time ago.

For now, we have checked IIS and AWS idle timeout but none seems to be relavant to the issue. And we are having no idea at all about what could possibly cause this issue.

If anyone had experienced similar situation or know potential direction that we could dig into, that would be really helpful!

Thanks!

========================================================================
We have tried adding logs to ensure the response is not blocked somewhere in the api or it reaches the service and we just didn't realize.

We have tried configured IIS and AWS timeout, the first does not seem to be relevant, the second is already over one hour so should not be the obstacle.

WE have tried specifying the api address to go to one specific server rather than load-balanced url, and this is still occurring.

Shorter responses do not have this problem. The shorter time it takes, the lower chance it could be lost.

Comment: Most web frameworks also set a default timeout. So, (1) your application code, (2) your webserver (IIS), and (3) AWS Load balancer _all_ must be configured to have appropriate timeout lengths. Additionally, depending on the nature of the client making the request, you _may_ also run into a problem with the client timing out, potentially due to a bad keep-alive configuration or strict timeouts in the client. Another possibility is that your request worker is stuck or died before returning a response. So triple-check your configs, restart IIS to ensure settings are applied, and add more logging.

Comment: @sytech Thanks for the comment, I will check on those mentioned.